# How can we attach jar libraries stored in workspace to job cluster in azure databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to attach jar files that I loaded in a folder in workspace but when I try to attach them to a task in a job that uses Jobs cluster - they are not visible.

Can someone please guide on this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have designed this extremely poorly.

Most likely you've uploaded your code to "dbfs" and you're looking for it in the "workspace", although the paths are the same, they are actually different locations.

Take your time to read "[Workspace libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/workspace-libraries)" 2-3 times slowly.

TL;DR

- Goto workspace.

[image]

- Navigate to where you want to store your lib.
- Right click on the folder you want to store it in and select Create -> Workspace Library. NOTE you can't navigate INTO the folder and use top right menu, you must right click on it. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

[image]

- Drag and drop/select the lib from your local machine, or other sources listed on the page.
- Add library

Now you should be able to go to job/cluster configuration, select workspace library, navigate to the folder and see the lib.